# Leaflet.Js - MarkerCluster - Popup Not Always Showing

Tags: javascript, jquery, maps, leaflet, markerclusterer

So I'm trying to use Leaflet.js, with MarkerCluster and get Popups to show. For some reason it seems to be tempramental. The popups aren't showing on every click.

This is the map code:

```
var map = L.map('map', {
        attributionControl: false,
        zoomControl: false,
        center: [53, -8],
        zoom: 6
    });

    //  Set the title layer
    L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.se/hydda/full/{z}/{x}/{y}.png').addTo(map);

    //  Add the zoom controls to the right side of the map
    new L.Control.Zoom({ position: 'topright' }).addTo(map);

    //  Custom marker icon
    var myIcon = L.icon({
        iconUrl: '../Content/images/macmillan-marker.png',
        iconSize: [30, 36],
        iconAnchor: [15, 36]
    });

    var markers = new L.MarkerClusterGroup();

    var ajax = $.ajax({
        url: '../Scripts/markers.js',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {

            var geoLayer = L.geoJson(data, {
                pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
                    return L.marker(latlng, { icon: myIcon });
                },
                onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
                    layer.bindPopup('Title');
                }
            });

            markers.addLayer(geoLayer);
        }

    });

    markers.on('click', function () {
        console.log('clicked');
    });

    map.addLayer(markers);
```

This is the markers.js file:

```
[{
    "type": "Point",
    "coordinates": [-8, 53]
},
{
    "type": "Point",
    "coordinates": [-10, 53]
},
{
    "type": "Point",
    "coordinates": [-8, 52]
},
{
    "type": "Point",
    "coordinates": [-8, 51]
},
{
    "type": "Point",
    "coordinates": [-8, 54]
},
{
    "type": "Point",
    "coordinates": [-9, 52]
},
{
    "type": "Point",
    "coordinates": [-8, 53]
}]
```

The points show on the map fine, and are being clustered correctly but as I say, the popup isn't always showing when clicking on the marker. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Can you make a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), so it'd be helpful to identify what is creating problem

Answer (score 0):

An extremely late answer to this question in case anyone else finds it. The solution I found was in this comment to a similar Issue on the github issue for the MarkerCluster repo

https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster/issues/431#issuecomment-106874944

"It seems that the app can get confused about the clickability of the circles if they are too close to the center of the cluster. So, adding the spiderfyDistanceMultiplier option with a value of 2 or more seems to help.
Still seems like a bug - but I think this workaround is adequate."

This fixed the problem for me

```js
    var markers = new L.MarkerClusterGroup({
               spiderfyDistanceMultiplier: 2
});
```